# Define the integral for the powerset of a countable set.

Tags: measure-theory

Say I have a countable set. I can sum over the elements of this set. Now, I take its powerset. I am no longer sum, but I can use the integral. How do I define an integral on the powerset of a countable set?

$$
\sum_{q\in\mathbb{N} } \to \int _{2^\mathbb{N}}dq
$$

It seems that the reals have so much more structure to support an integral than the powerset of a countable set. For example, they are ordered, and continuous and form ranges, etc...

Comment: Integral of a non-negative function $f$ w.r.t the counting measure on the powers set of $X$ is the supremum of $\sum_{x \in F} f(x)$ where the supremum is taken over  all finite sets $F \subset X$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But where do the notions of ordered and continuous and ranges that the reals have come from.... Or are you saying these are not necessary to define an integral?

Comment: You can write sums as Lebesgue integrals w.r.t. a counting measure.

Comment: What's necessary for an integral is a measure. If you can define a measure on the power set, then you can integrate over it.